# ClassCastException while using ThriftData for serializing Thrift data in Avro format

Tags: java, serialization, avro, thrift

We are trying to find a way to serialize Thrift schema into Avro format.

The flow is as follows:

We have a project 'A' which uses Thrift. The output result object is a thrift based object.

We have project 'B' which uses Avro. We would like to read the project 'A' Thrift schema and produce compatible Avro schema for project 'B'.

We have tried using the [ThriftData](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/thrift/ThriftData.html) provided in Apache Avro to serialize the Thrift schema

```
Schema schema = thriftData.getSchema(XYZ.class);
```

The execution fails with the message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.thrift.meta_data.FieldValueMetaData cannot be cast to org.apache.thrift.meta_data.StructMetaData
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: A full stacktrace and a minimal example for XYZ would greatly help.

Comment: @ArvidHeise the exception seems to occur [here](https://github.com/rdblue/avro-java/blob/master/thrift/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/thrift/ThriftData.java#L256). amrutasaraf did you manually modify the Java generated class by Thrift? Maybe you changed the *type* field? Can you show us the *.thrift* file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check *valueMetaData* property to check if it has a correct type.